# Should I use SignalR to synchronize & cache CRUD data to a mobile app?

Tags: javascript, architecture, mobile

I'm considering using SignalR to send data to a mobile app, but need to have a way to synchronize data while it's closed or pending updates.

Is it a good idea to use Backbone.js <--> SignalR to manage queued CRUD updates to the server?  If not, what is?

Comment: Do you obtain solution for that?